# sending all kinds of file(image, video, pdf, etc) from client to server and vice versa with socket.io

Tags: node.js, image, pdf, video, socket.io

Is there any useful tutorial on how to send and receive all kinds of files from client to server with socket.io? my client is in Java and my server is in node js. java side is not important to me. I just want to handle files on the server. receiving files through socket.io on the server and emit them to others in the room.

Answer (score 1):

socket.io isn't really the best way to send large amounts of data, i'd recommend looking into POST requests, they are normally used for large files like images and text paragraphs

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp